# The term 'submit50' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: pip, cs50

I'm using VScode in windows 11, with the integrated powershell terminal.
After running `pip3 install submit50` (and also `pip3 install --upgrade submit50` just in case).

When running `submit50 ai50/projects/2020/x/tictactoe` I get the following error:

```
submit50 : The term 'submit50' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path   
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
+ submit50 ai50/projects/2020/x/tictactoe
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (submit50:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

other python and pip commands are running fine on my machine.
What did I do wrong here?

Python: `Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Pip: `pip 22.0.3 from C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`

Comment: What is `submit50`? Is it a cmdlet? A function? A script? A program? Check that the definition is in scope / on the path / has been loaded, as appropriate for the type of thing it is.

Comment: `submit50` is a command line tool. https://cs50.readthedocs.io/submit50/

Comment: So make sure it is on your path.

Comment: Where is the executable to add to path and why pip didn't do that already?

Comment: I assume the executable is "submit50". You'll have to ask the author of `submit50` why it's not getting installed correctly.